# MySQL REPLACE and DUPLICATE KEY not giving sum of column value

Tags: mysql, replace, key, sql-update, duplicates

I have table with following format StoreID | ItemID | ItemName | Qty . StoreID and ItemID are Pkeys.Im trying to execute mysql query and insert StoreID ='ST1 ' ItemID ='IT1' ItemName='IT' Qty=1000 But here i want to insert the record if not exists, if exists update the Qty = Qty+ 100.I tried using mysql Replace into and Duplicate key update. It does what i want to do, except Qty not increasing.Both queries below set Qty to 0 when execute first time. As i can understand thats because there is no duplicate entry at the first time.
What i want to do is add the record if not exists with given qty and update only qty each time it execute afterwards

```
INSERT INTO Store_Items (storeID, itemId,itemName)  
VALUES ('STR004', '4534','K40')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currentStock = currentStock + 100;  


REPLACE INTO Store_Items  
        SET storeID ='STR004',  
         itemId='4534',  
         itemName='K40',  
         SUM(currentStock) as 'Total',  
         reorderLevel=1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your query should look like

```sql
INSERT INTO Store_Items (storeID, itemId, itemName, Qty)  
VALUES ('STR004', '4534','K40', 100)  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Qty = IFNULL(Qty, 0) + 100;
```

After first insert:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+
| storeID | itemId | itemName | Qty  |
+---------+--------+----------+------+
| STR004  |   4534 | K40      |  100 |
+---------+--------+----------+------+
```

After second insert:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+
| storeID | itemId | itemName | Qty  |
+---------+--------+----------+------+
| STR004  |   4534 | K40      |  200 |
+---------+--------+----------+------+
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e23aa/1)**

Comment: Oh yes.Thank you so much. your the best. i tried to sort out this last 24hrs continuously.